# Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу (Исключение HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Tags: iis, faq, iis-express

При попытке запустить сайт в IIS появляется окно с ошибкой:

> Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят
>   другим процессом. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80070020)

[image: Скриншот исключения]

Сайт развернут на 80 порту. Ранее такой ошибки не наблюдал. Около недели назад появлялась эта ошибка, но перезапуск Visual Studio решил проблему и больше ошибка не появлялась. Сейчас ошибка появилась вновь, но ни перезапуск  Visual Studio, ни перезагрузка компьютера не решили проблему. Кто сталкивался с данной проблемой, подскажите, как решить? Нашел пару статей по похожим ошибкам, но везде не то.

---

Нашел вот эту статью: [Ошибка 0x80070020 при использовании сайта Центра обновления Windows или Центра обновления Майкрософт для установки обновлений](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/883825)

Обновил систему, перезагрузил компьютер, очистил мусор, скопившийся в системе, перезагрузил компьютер - не решило проблемы. Да, понимаю, что ошибка в IIS, но на всякий случай проверил. Антивируса у меня на компьютере нет.

Comment: *Только хотел написать что 100 раз на этот вопрос отвечали... и не нашел прошлых ответов :)* Добавил метку faq, потому что этот вопрос сейчас возникает практически **у каждого** начинающего веб-программиста.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да я вот тоже искал-искал и что-то безуспешно... Подумал, что будет кому-то полезно. Мне бы помогло.

Comment: У меня этот процесс называется svchost (netsvcs) его ронять - добровольно повесить комп, ибо это системный процесс. Но если все-таки уронить, таки да, сайт запускается

Comment: @Dmitry, если процесс `svchost (netsvcs)` занимает 80-порт, то я думаю, что тут что-то неладное, похоже на вирус, но возможно я ошибаюсь. Есть еще способ - сменить порт для сайта в IIS. Зайдите в привязки и там установите другой порт, к примеру 8080, в общем любой не занятый.

Comment: @DenisBubnov нет, это как раз нормально. 80й порт через HTTP.SYS много кто слушает, не только IIS. Правда, IISу такие слушатели - не помеха, видимо Dmitry как-то по-другому сайт запускал.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, я потом уже додумался до того, что слушателей 80 порта много...но как так удалось запустить сайт - остается загадкой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение проблемы оказалось следующим:

1. Запустить командную строку и написать в ней команду:

> ```
> netstat -aon | find ":80"
> ```

в результате, в окне командной строки будет видно следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо найти процесс, который прослушивает необходимый нам порт. 
Здесь мы видим, что процесс с идентификатором `3544` прослушивает *занятый* 80 порт.

2. Открываем диспетчер задач и ищем там этот процесс по идентификатору(ИД):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видим - это программа Skype. Открываем Skype,  и выполняем следующие действия:

> Инструменты -> Настройки... -> Дополнительно -> Соединение

В появившемся окне будет несколько настроек, нас интересует *«Для дополнительных входящих соединений следует использовать порты 80 и 443»*, поэтому убираем активную галочку:

> Для дополнительных входящих соединений следует использовать порты 80 и
>   443

Сохраняем изменения. Перезапускаем Skype, заходим в <kbd>Диспетчер служб IIS</kbd> и запускаем сайт, который во время попытки запуска валился с ошибкой.

Подсказка для решения была найдена на MSDN: [Ошибка 0x80070020 при запуске веб-сайта в IIS 7.0](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/973094)