# Как на своём пк, создать простейший http сервер, имея в распоряжении белый IP

Tags: windows, сервер, http

Как на своём пк, создать простейший http сервер, имея в распоряжении белый IP,
Чтобы перейдя по ссылке http://мой IP/картинка.jpg
открыть картинку?

Это всё что нужно.. просто открыть картинку, которая лежит в корне диска на пк.

Ютюб заваливает какими то сложными решениями, в которых сложно разобраться.

Можно даже в одной wifi сети.

Comment: Решением оказалась программа HFS

Comment: [powershell-web-server.ps1](https://gist.github.com/19WAS85/54244310)

Answer (score 4):

Есть ещё программа "SmallHttpServer" - полноценный сервак размером 200 Кб. Может работать FTP/DNS/прокси/почтовым сервером. Имеется поддержка GZip, SSI, CGI (включая интерпретаторы PHP, Perl и др.), виртуальных хостов и директорий, POP3, SMTP, почтовых антиспам фильтров. Поддерживаются протоколы FTP, HTTPS. Сервер ведёт подробную статистику, есть возможность администрирования через веб или локально

Comment: Столь неинформативные ответы не приветствуются сообществом. Можете дополнить свой ответ, расписав преимущества/недостатки данной программы?

Comment: Отредактировал..

Answer (score 1):

Самый штатный способ в Windows - это использование Internet Information Services, сокращенно IIS.

Устанавливается IIS как компонент Windows, на Windows 10 с русской локализацией это делается следующим образом:

1. ПКМ на ту кнопку, которая теперь вместо "Пуск",
2. Выбрать пункт "Приложения и возможности";
3. Справа есть ссылка "Программы и компоненты";
4. Слева есть пункт "Включение и отключение компонентов Windows".

В открывшемся списке нужно выбрать пункт "Службы IIS". Если его раскрыть - будет видно, что эти службы состоят из очень большого набора фич - но по умолчанию выбираются только самые базовые. И этого базового набора будет достаточно.

На всякий случай прикладываю картинку как это должно выглядеть:

[image: Скриншот]

Вот и всё, сервер установлен. Теперь осталось положить вашу картинку в папку C:\inetpub\wwwroot - и её можно будет увидеть по прямой ссылке.

PS возможные проблемы:

1. Скайп "любит" занимать 80й порт, да и другие программы могут делать то же самое. При занятом порте IIS не сможет запустить сайт. Процесс "лечения" описан тут: [Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу (Исключение HRESULT: 0x80070020)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565546/178779)
2. Порт может быть закрыт брандмауэром. По умолчанию он открывается при установке IIS, но если что-то пошло не так - может понадобиться открыть его вручную.
3. Порт может быть закрыт на роутере. В таком случае придётся настраивать роутер.
4. Порт может быть закрыт провайдером. Тут может помочь звонок провайдеру, но если там откажутся открывать порт - ничего не поделать. Хотя может помочь VPN с белым IP, если такие существуют.

Answer (score -1):

https://mongoose.ws/

Поставь его, запускается одной кнопкой и в папку с программой кидаешь нужные картинки

Есть ещё openserver

Если более профессионально то nginx

Comment: Это вирус! Что это за программа такая?!

Comment: @ДаниэлльГранд, а с чего ты взял, что это вирус?

Comment: windows пишет - вредоносный файл.
даже когда жмёшь всё равно установить, в итоге удаляет и пишет что критическая угроза.

Comment: @ДаниэлльГранд, поставьте Linux

Comment: @ДаниэлльГранд там точно не вирус ) погугли по названию. Возможно не официальным сертификатом подписана программа ( платный денег стоит) вот при загрузке из внешнего источника браузер ругается

Comment: @ДенисЗахаренко там и правда вирус: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/a3cbc928b5d0cabd7afa969e0731545b702193509051e6b7dbdcfc08c94b3d67

Comment: для сравнения: вот как выглядит правильный файл - https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/55b27629076d0649950029e3e6650ef0031eea862cff80a1a12607d36251b2b0